# XeLaTex: error on Z operator of an equation

Tags: xetex, amsmath, math-operators

I try to write the following equation using amsmath:

[image: Equation]

So far I tried the following approaches:

```
$H : G \rightarrow \Z_{q}^{*}$
$H : G \rightarrow \Zeta_{q}^{*}$
```

But both of them result to erroneous situation:

> Undefined control sequence. ...e way hash function $H : G \rightarrow \Z

Can you help me why?

Comment: `\Z` is not a command defined in any of the standard packages, did you mean to use simply `Z` ?

Comment: You probably want `\mathbb{Z}` or to define `\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}` in the preamble. It requires `\usepackage{amssymb}` (or `\usepackage{amsfonts}`, but the former package provides more).